# Unable to assign static ip using Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vmware

I am using Vagrant and vagrant-vshpere plugin to deploy VM on vCenter. Vagrant deploys the VM but it fails to assign the ip address for the VM. Could any body let me know do i need to make specific changes in order for the ip address to be assigned?

Here are the contents of my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'dummy'
  config.vm.box_url = './example_box/dummy.box'
  config.vm.network :public_network, ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

  config.vm.provider :vsphere do | vsphere |
    vsphere.host = '<vSphere_Host>'
    vsphere.data_center_name = '<Data_Center_Name>'
    vsphere.data_store_name = '<Data_Store_Name>'
    vsphere.template_name = '<Template_Name>'
    vsphere.name = '<New_Name_Of_The_VM>'
    vsphere.user = '<vShpere_User_Name>'
    vsphere.password = '<The_Password>'
    vsphere.insecure = true
    vsphere.compute_resource_name = '<Compute_Resource_IP>'
  end
end
```

Note: The template that i am uploading is a custom template [a linux box with some applications running on top of it]

Answer (score 1):

You can set static ip with a private network..

try with this  network configuration 
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"